# Unable to trigger Signal to stop block in Project Reactor

Tags: project-reactor

I want to try `blockOptional` in Project Reactor. According to the description, it is used to

> Subscribe to this Mono and block indefinitely until a next signal is
>   received or the Mono completes empty

I tried the following
.

```
Mono<Void> triggerSignal() {
    Signal.next("signal");
}

triggerSignal()
    .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .blockOptional();

System.out.println("Outside chain");
```

I expect to see "Outside chain" printed before the 30s delay. However I have to wait 30s.

Isn't a signal received and the block should stop when a signal received? Is it the correct way to send a signal?

Answer (score 1):

`triggerSignal()` does indeed produce a signal immediately.

However, the next item in your chain is a `delayElement()` call which will *always* delay the element emitted by 30s (before it reaches the next operator in the reactive chain); hence `blockOptional()` will never "see" the signal before 30s has elapsed.

It sounds like you want to, instead, block for *up to* 30s while you wait for the signal. If that's the case, then you can pass a duration to `blockOptional()` instead of delaying the element, such as:

```
triggerSignal()
    .blockOptional(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```